# Azure Storage Table complex query

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am trying to query Azure Table which has column property such as `Azure Resource Name`, `Blackoutperiodstartdate`, `Blackoutperiodenddate` having Partition Key set to resourceId of the respective Azure Resource Name, however I am getting the following error:

> azure.TableQuery.CombineFilters is not a constructor

while executing the below code using Azure Functions(HttptriggerJavascript)

```
var pkFilter = new azure.TableQuery().where('PartitionKey eq ?', 'coewebapptestid');
var resourceFilter = new azure.TableQuery().where('resourcename eq ?', 'coewebapptest');
var combinedFilter = new azure.TableQuery.CombineFilters(pkFilter, TableOperators.And, resourceFilter);

var tablequery = new azure.TableQuery().where(combinedFilter);

tableService.queryEntities('blackoutperiodtable', tablequery, null, function(error, result){
    if(!error){
        // Entity available in serverEntity variable

    }
```

I am looking out to use multiple 'where' or 'combine filter' to basically query the Partition key and then find the associated resource name property value along with start date & end date values from the Azure Table as an output of my table query.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for [`combineFilters`](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/TableQuery.html#.combineFilters__anchor), you will notice that it is a `static` method thus you can't really create an instance of this.

Try something like this:

```
var combinedFilter = azure.TableQuery.CombineFilters(pkFilter, TableOperators.And, resourceFilter);
```

Comment: I am getting the following error..azure.TableQuery.CombineFilters is not a function

Comment: Getting the following error... mscorlib: TypeError: azure.TableQuery.CombineFilters is not a function

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple workaround to your query. I recently took advantage of Cerebrata where we can select the specific Azure Storage attribute to create a query, define the operator (=, >, <, not equal), specify the name & value based on attribute name & value (To define and query the partition key), segment the attribute type (String or Date/Time) followed by logical connectors (And/Or).

Also, the tools help us to choose from a set of predefined dates including Start Date and End Date, and the tool will output the value from the Azure table in a properly formatted way.

Disclaimer: It’s purely based on my experience

[image]